# How do I get information about how an index set was created in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

A long time ago I created a CTXCAT index with an INDEX SET using ctx_ddl.create_index_set and ctx_ddl.add_index but forgot to save the DDL anywhere and now I need to recreate this index on another server and I want to make sure the indexes are created in the same manner.  How do I get what columns are included in an index set?  I know the name of the INDEX SET, I just am trying to figure out what columns are included in it.

Comment: Did you take a look at dbms_metadata.get_ddl ? Perhaps that package can help you.